# Display Value From Another Row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to write a query to display the value for ID2 when ID=ID. Currently the table looks like the below.

| ID | ID2 | fname | lname | address1 | address2 | city | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 | joe | smith | 12 main st |  | los angeles | CA |
| 122 | 122 | james | jones | 13 main st |  | new york | NY |
| 123 | **3210** | joe | smith | 14 main st |  | los angeles | CA |
| 124 | 124 | mary | jones | 15 main st |  | new york | NY |

The desired output would look like this. Where I can do some sort of a self join to get the ID2 value.

| ID | ID2 | fname | lname | address1 | address2 | city | state | other ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 | joe | smith | 12 main st |  | los angeles | CA | **3210** |
| 122 | 122 | james | jones | 13 main st |  | new york | NY |  |
| 124 | 124 | mary | jones | 15 main st |  | new york | NY |  |

Any ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Update:

I was able to get the result with the additional columns using the below script. Thanks all for your assistance on this one!

```
with cte (id, id2, fname, lname, address1, address2, city, state)
as (select *
from (select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by id desc) as rn from your_table
) x
where rn = 2)
select x.id, x.id2, x.fname, x.lname, x.address1, x.address2, x.city, x.state, c.id2, c.address1
from (select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by id desc) as rn from your_table
) x
left join
cte c on x.id=c.id
where x.rn = 1
```

dbfiddle below
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=4010ab08c5e32d9293d10e985adbfd7a

Comment: What happens if there are  two or more ID2 rows?

Comment: currently the table only has a maximum of one extra ID2 value.  I did a row_number() over(partition by ID order by ID) and had max count of 2.

Comment: In which case the answer suggested should be fine, it's always best to code for the eventuality to ensure unexpected data doesn't break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following, using a correlated subquery; using `max` ensures it only returns a single row should you have an Id with more than one different ID2:

```
select *,
    (select max(id2) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.id2 != t.id) OtherId
from t
where id = id2
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked as expected. In the event I needed to grab the value address1 from subquery max ID2 would that be possible? and show it in the same row

| ID  | ID2 | fname | lname | address1   | address2 | city        | state | other ID | otheraddress |
|-----|-----|-------|-------|------------|----------|-------------|-------|----------|--------------|
| 123 | 123 | joe   | smith | 12 main st |          | los angeles | CA    | 3210     | 14 main st   |

Comment: Note if you needed additional columns (your question doesn't ask that) you could user a *lateral join* instead.

Comment: k let me try the lateral join. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two rows max with the same id, then you can try this :

```
SELECT (array_agg(t.*) FILTER (WHERE id = id2))[1].*
     , (array_agg(t.id2) FILTER (WHERE id <> id2))[1] AS "other ID"
  FROM your_table AS t
 GROUP BY id
```

If you may have more than two rows with the same id then you can try this :

```
SELECT (array_agg(t.*) FILTER (WHERE id = id2))[1].*
     , array_agg(t.id2) FILTER (WHERE id <> id2) AS "other IDs"
  FROM your_table AS t
 GROUP BY id
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f33deceeca344f91850d3dfa15c99cd8)

Comment: I was trying to use your script to test but could not get it working due to edit saying incorrect data type. I can post the exact error syntax tomorrow from work.